# How to create battlement for castle with geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I created a simple castle and I need to create a battlement on top of it.
[image]
How can I do it with geometry nodes? I thought about creating a simple cube with bevel and use it with Instance on points, but result is not so good(
[image]
P.S. I need battlement only for facade, so I didn't created additional vertices for back side.

Comment: @JachymMichal well, now I know what it's called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your curve doesn't have too sharp corners, you could start with this:

[image]

[image]

I started here with a curve, which has the flexibility, that you can "draw" your castle like this:

[image]

Important is the resample curve node here with length, so you can accurately define the distance between each hole. With the curve tangent node you can rotate them in the curve-normals direction (by adding 90 degrees which is pi in radians). Hope it helps, happy blending!

Comment: Thank you! But I have couple of additional questions. In that case how can I "fill" the castle? Because, as I understand, it's empty inside so we have only the walls. And second question - I see that you are not drawing to the end, but the contur you get is closed. How?

Comment: you can check "cyclic U" in "active spline" in curve settings, so it is closed

Comment: may i ask you why you want it to be "filled"? No geometry is ever "filled" as you think ;) because you only see the "visible faces" -> inside it's always "empty", but you won't see it. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. If you have additional/other question, feel free to open new questions. You should not ask in comments because everybody else cannot see the answer then. Thx.

Comment: I suppose it's misunderstanding, I just talking about the roof)

Comment: you are right, you can use fill curve for these things like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vli1N.jpg

Comment: Oh, cool! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome